# Getting instance and field id of jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've found a bunch of similar questions for this issue but none of their answers seems to work here. I have a Datepicker in a website where the input of a date is checked when the user is typing. It works well but I also want to have the date colored in realtime when the input is not valid. For that I need the id of the input field the Datepicker is associated with.

When using `onClose` function in Datepicker definiton, I get `inst` which is the instance of the current Datepicker object and by `inst.id` I get the field name. But this does not work in the `parseDate` function. I also can't pass on `inst` or make it global, because `onClose` is never executed before `parseDate`. I tried `$(this).attr('id')` as suggested somewhere but it returns `undefined`. My code (minimal example):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  $(function () {
    $(".dp").datepicker({
      showOn: "focus",
      showMonthAfterYear: false,
      dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
      onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        console.log("field name : ", inst.id); //works, inst.id is 'startDate'.
        $("#" + inst.id + ".form-control.dp.hasDatepicker").css("color", "red"); //works, inst.id is 'startDate'.
      }
    });

    $.datepicker.parseDate = function (format, value, settings) {
      var field = $(this).attr("id"); //not working, field is null.
      $("#" + field + ".form-control.dp.hasDatepicker").css("color", "red"); //not working, field is null.
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ __('Start') }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="text" class="form-control dp" id="startDate" name="start" value="">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , can you make your code runnable ?

Comment: It's not necessary, the issue is obvious.

Comment: It is obvious to you... Which `datepicker` plugin are you using? [Date picker list](https://cdnjs.com/libraries?q=datepicker)

Comment: @louys as per the tag mentioned by the user it should be jQuery-ui ... Just to help you

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Is there more than 1 Datepicker in jQuery? I am using https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ...and yes, the issue is well illustrated and does not need a runable version. Sorry there's no toy to play with, just a riddle to solve.

Comment: So is this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/QWKzNEN?editors=1010) close to what you have?

Comment: Seems so, thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Swati What exactly is unclear about my question, so that you need a runable version?

Comment: What is unclear now is `...the input of a date is checked when the user is typing. It works well but I also want to have the date colored in realtime...` There actually is no date "check" for a direct date typing (not using the datepicker popover), but that is what you would like to have, right?

Comment: No. As stated above, " I need the id of the input field the Datepicker is associated with" inside the `parseDate` function. A minimal example only shows what is important regarding the issue.

Comment: That is what you think you need to have in order to achieve something. What I'm asking is about what you wish to achieve. -- By the way, your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What I wish to achieve is in my question above: " I want to have the date colored in realtime when the input is not valid." When you know a better way to achieve this ofc I would like to see it. I am always keen for code improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would perform the date validity with a `input` event handler aside the date picker... Because that date check you wish to have is not a feature of datepicker.

So on `input`, evaluate the `new Date` value to add an `.invalid` class to the `input` like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".dp").datepicker({
    showOn: "focus",
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
  });

  $(".dp").on("input", function () {
  
    // Remove the class on each new input
    $(this).removeClass("invalid");

    let currentVal = $(this).val();
    console.log(currentVal);

    // Split the value
    let dateParts = currentVal.split(".");
    
    // If incomplete
    if (dateParts.length !== 3) {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
      return;
    }

    // Create a date object to evaluate
    let validDate = new Date(`${dateParts[2]}-${dateParts[1]}-${dateParts[0]} 00:00:00`);
    console.log(validDate.toString());

    // If the date is "invalid" and does not have 4 digits for the year (because it could be valid anyway... But obviously wrong)
    if (validDate.toString() === "Invalid Date" || dateParts[2].length !== 4) {
      $(this).addClass("invalid");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dp.invalid{
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ __('Start') }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="text" class="form-control dp" id="startDate" name="start" value="">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KKgbzBq?editors=1111)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I get the idea. Out of curiosity: What is the difference between `$(".dp").on("input", function(){` and `$.datepicker.parseDate = function(format,value,settings){` ? And why do you prefer classes for coloring over my notation?

Comment: `$(".dp").on("input", function(){` is an event handler. `$.datepicker.parseDate = ...` is assigning a function to the `datepicker` plugin... So it may overwrite an existing function and mess the picker. -- About the class `.invalid`, it's just easier to add or remove it than directly change the style attribute of the input. ALSO, you can now check is this class is present on submit... ;)